# Set maximum number of joint rotations per plan

Tags: ros, python, path-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm issuing my robot move commands in a way similar to this tutorial:

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html

However, many of the plans it comes up with have unnecessary joint rotations. Is there to specify the maximum amount a joint can rotate for a planned path programmatically (ie no more than two full rotations or no more than 720 degrees movement in the joint during the plan execution)? If not, is there a way to set it manually?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264781/set-maximum-number-of-joint-rotations-per-plan/) by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-26**:
Can you perhaps clarify a bit what you mean with 'unnecessary joint rotations'? I'm not saying your question is one, but just to avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

**Comment by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on 2017-06-26**:
For simple planned paths, the head of the robot will just keep rotating throughout the movement, where very little if any rotation looks like it would be needed. I don't know if it did it before I attached a new tool, but with the tool attached the rotation is extremely apparent.

**Comment by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on 2017-06-26**:
I think its joint_6 of the lrmate200id rotating if that makes a difference. Also, in regards to the XY problem, I suppose that problem X would be that the planners are coming up with strange paths with unnecessary rotations and movements

**Comment by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on 2017-06-28**:
You could use minimum and maximum values of the different joints inside the urdf file.

**Comment by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on 2017-06-28**:
For the URDF, would that be 's  and  tags? That seems like what I'm looking for, although I'm not sure what "lower/upper joint limit" means

**Comment by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on 2017-06-29**:
Joint limits describe the "move-range" of your joint. lower/upper are similar to from/til. See code example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As i mentioned above, one solution could be to use lower and upper limits inside your urdf file.

```
<joint name="articulated" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link1_rot"/>
    <child link="link2_lin"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <origin xyz ="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-1.5" upper="1.5" velocity="0.5"/>
</joint>
```

The joint "articulated", which connects link1_rot and link2_lin can now spin around the y-axis from -90 to +90 degrees.

---

Originally posted by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) with karma: 115 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0